# How to write method interceptor triggered by annotation using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm using Spring 2.5 for dependency injection management. I have a few classes that need to have some action triggered in the background when certain methods are called. I figured that the easiest way to do this would be with an annotation, like:

```
class MyClass {
  //...
  @DoSomethingElseInTheBackground
  function void doSomething() {
  //...
  }
  //...
}
```

I've written a [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) before and that was quite simple. So is there a way to do what I'm looking for? I'm inspired, in part, by `@Transational`.

Comment: Can I use a parameter of `doSomething()` in my background process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correctly inspired by `@Transactional`. It uses [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html), built-in feature of Spring framework.

Have a look at: [@AspectJ examples with pointcuts based on annotations](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/18/aspectj-examples-with-pointcuts-based-on-annotations/) which describes the exact same use case.